# Segmentation Fault 11 in C++ when accessing second element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers, segmentation-fault

In short, I have a C++ program that consists of a Car class with subclasses SportsCar and SUV, as well as a CarInventory that stores the Car objects.

Comment: What does your `insert` method look like?

Comment: Why does your `insert` function take pointers? Why are you constructing a bunch of cars on the stack when you want them to be owned by a class? Is `inventorySize` supposed to be the number of cars you actually have? If so, where is it set to the value? If not, why are you printing that many cars?

Comment: Inventory size represents the max number of cars that can be in the inventory stock. I will add my insert method  to my original post. I'm very new to c++ so pointers are what I struggle with quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the insert function

```
void CarInventory::insert(Car *car) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < inventorySize; i++) {
        if (carArray[i]) { 
            i++;
        }
```

When you find a car already in in your `carArray` you increment `i`, but then you increment `i` again in the for-loop. That way you will skip every other position in the array, and they will remain uninitialized.

Comment: That was it Bo. Haha i should've seen that. I used continue; instead of i++ and it worked.

Comment: I think there's another danger in the way the OP is adding elements to his inventory. He's allocating `Car` objects on the stack and inserting them as `&obj`, which is a **stack address**. These stack addresses will remain valid only as long as the function itself has not returned. After that, the `Car`s in the stack get pop'ed and he'll end up with invalid addresses in his container, leading to segfaults. What he should do is create the `Car`s in the heap using the `new` operator and make sure to clean up `Car` instances when the `CarInventory` is being destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You allocated an array of 10 cars.  But you only initialized it with 4 cars.

So when your loop in `displayVehichles` gets around to accessing `carArray[5]` it will likely be accessing uninitialized memory.

This statement seems troublesome:

```
carArray = new Car *[maxStock];
```

It should probably be:

```
carArray = new Car *[maxStock];
for (int i = 0; i < maxStock; i++)
{
    carArray[i] = NULL;
}
totalNumCars = 0;
```

That way, your insert method will behave correctly.  But your insert method could be much simpler:

```
void CarInventory::insert(Car *car) { 

    if (totalNumCars < maxStock)
        carArray[totalNumCars] = car;
        totalNumCars++;
    }
}
```

Further, while it's OK the way you have it the cars you have declared go out of scope BEFORE your CarInventory goes out of scope, it will be referencing Car objects that have already been deleted.

Use std::vector to hold your cars:

```
class CarInventory
{
    std::vector<Car*> _cars;
 public:
    void displayVehicles()
    {
        for (auto i = _cars.begin(); i != _cars.end(); i++)
        {
            i->printInfo();
        }
    }

    void insert(Car* car)
    {
        _cars.push_back(car);
    }
};
```

Now that still doesn't solve the problem of your CarInventory class holding onto pointers of stack objects.

This is even better:

```
class CarInventory
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>> _cars;
 public:
    void displayVehicles()
    {
        for (auto i = _cars.begin(); i != _cars.end(); i++)
        {
            i->printInfo();
        }
    }

    void insert(std::shared_ptr<Car>& spCar)
    {
        _cars.push_back(spCar);
    }
};
```

Then your code to use the class:

```
std::shared_ptr<Car*> createCar(const char* vin, const char* make, const char* color, int year)
{
    Car* car = new Car(vin, make, color, year);
    return std::shared_ptr<Car>(car);
}

int main(int argn, char *argv[])
{
   CarInventory cars;

   std::shared_ptr<Car*> toyota = createCar("2GCGC34M9F1152828", "Toyota", "Camry", "Green", 2012);

   std::shared_ptr<Car*> honda = createCar("1C4BJWAG4DL602733", "Honda", "Civic", "Blue", 2015);

    ...

    CarInventory cars;
    cars.insert(toyota);
    cars.insert(honda);
    cout << "\n";
    cars.displayVehicles();
}
```

Comment: *"cars you have declared go out of scope BEFORE your CarInventory goes out of scope"* - not true... function-local automatic variables are "destructed" in opposite order to declaration/construction.

Comment: @TonyD - Correct. I'm merely pointing out that if his "carsInventory" variable out lives the cars themselves - because it's in an outer scope, he will have problems. I'm steering him towards reference counted shared_ptr class.

Comment: Hi Selbie, thanks so much for the help. This project requires that I use array of pointers to pointers for the cars. Is there any way to do this using the array? I tried allocating an array of 4 cars and I still receive the segmentation fault error.

Comment: After you call `carArray = new Car *[maxStock];` you need to make sure all the values in that array are `NULL`. `for (i = 0; i < maxStock; i++) {carArray[i] = NULL;}`  That's probably why you are crashing.

Comment: @gtlorenzo93 - I've added some more stuff to my answer above to address the issue with your class member initialization. Basically, you should initialize totalNumCars in your constructor to zero as well as zero-init your array.